# Differentiation of a function multiplied by a constant

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm a newbie to calculus yesterday I was learning some basics of differentiation for physics. Just of out of curiousity, if we have to differentiate two functions which are a product but multiplied with a constant term,

For example **d/dx (2*sinx²*cosx²)**
I can use the product rule for **sinx²** and **cosx²** but what to do with the constant 2.

Will it be **2(d/dx (sinx²*cosx²))?**
Kindly help me out with this. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Because the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ is linear, you can safely move any constant, such as $2$, outside.

Another way to go about it is to apply the product rule to $2\sin^2x$ and $\cos^2x$, or any other combination of multiplicands that you see. You can check that this gives you the same answer.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot